# Create a button click handler for any page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jquery-events

I am trying to make a Chrome extension. My goal is to do the following:

1. To run a certain JavaScript when a button or link with specific id is clicked.
2. That button or link with specific id could be on any web site.

My code looks really simple but I am not sure where I am missing. Will the jQuery not work this way in Chrome extension? Is there any equivalent code in plain JavaScript?

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Handle a button click",
  "version": "1.1",
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "name": "click to handle"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.9.0.min.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_submit").click(function(){
        alert("yo");
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**  AFter debugging for background.js I am seeing:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

jQuery file is not getting included? or why?

Comment: the id of the element i want to listen the click event, actually that "specific id" i was talking about

Comment: Also that `manifest.json` if it is a static file it might be blocked from the browser if it's directly addresses within the OS with no proxy server .

Comment: Yeah I can see that it's an id of an element but is it selected?

Comment: I followed the tutorial and actually edited a working extension, why should it be blocking ? .... "is it selected?" i don't get it, its just a simple click listener function isn't it ?

Comment: I was just making a point,  there's no common between it and the issue posted. But if it's working good

Comment: Ahh, Thanks any way for spending your good time to try to help Cheers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).click(function(event){
    if(event.target.id == "my_submit"){    
        alert("yo");
    }
    });
});
```

This checks al the click events if the element that fires the click event has id `my_submit` and if so, alert

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnvvQ/)

Comment: doesn't wor , when i inspect element i get error in the background.js saying  "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" :'(

Comment: but that "content_scripts" is the way to insert jquery when u write chrome extension isn't it ?

Comment: @cjmling, yes, and your own script after it.. that's how i do it. first jquery, and then your own script in the content_scripts line...

Comment: Hurray, yeah thats work... i tried putting my own script before jquery ,but not after.  Never thought of that :S  Thanks Alot

Comment: @cjmling, no problem, happend me before to. Glad i could help :D